# How to correctly await on lambda Func delegate C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I am confused on the correct way to use the pass the lambda to func delegate for the httpClient.

E.g. The Call is a generic function where there is an await on the TaskFunctor function delegate.

What should be the correct way to pass a HttpClient in lamda function for the taskFunctor so it can await for the response ?

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Call(string operationId, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> taskFunctor)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                response = await taskFunctor();
                s_tracer.Trace(0, "Got response for {0}: {1}", operationId, response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                s_tracer.Trace(0, "Got response for {0}: {1}", operationId, ex.Message);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

What is the correct way for the make pass lambda ?

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync2(string requestUri)
        {
            string absoluteRequestUri = requestUri;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await Call(
                string.Format("HttpClientFacade:Get {0}", requestUri),
                async() => await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)); <<<<<<ASYNC Lamda

            return response;
        }
```

**OR**

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync1(string requestUri)
        {
            string absoluteRequestUri = requestUri;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await Call(
                string.Format("HttpClientFacade:Get {0}", requestUri),
                () => httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri));  <<<<<<Lamda

            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, they're practically the same. For trivial lambdas, feel free to [elide `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). However, if your lambda does *anything* non-trivial (i.e., anything that could cause exceptions, or any `using` statements), then you should keep the `async`/`await` in.

Removing the `async`/`await` gives you an immeasurably small performance benefit, but the code is more likely to remain correct over time if you leave them in.